# Is Supports Second Level Address Translation (EPT or NPT) required to use Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, prerequisites

This page, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/get-started/system-requirements--and-installation says I need:

Supports Second Level Address Translation (EPT or NPT)

to run Hyper-V.

I read elsewhere that I don't really need it, unless I want RemoteFX.

Do I need to have EPT or NPT to run Hyper-V (2012 or 2016)?  My processor is Intel Xeon CPU E5-2620 v4 @ 2.10Ghz, but apparently I have the implementation that has everything except EPT.  There is not BIOS setting for it, so I am thinking the server motherboard simply cannot support it.

Comment: Huh? [This processor supports EPT.](http://ark.intel.com/products/92986/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v4-20M-Cache-2_10-GHz)

Comment: What about the footnote?

Comment: What about it? It says you also have to use compatible motherboards, firmware, etc.

Comment: I don't have that evidently.

Comment: Then the fault isn't with your processor, as you stated. You probably have something in the BIOS turned off that should be on.

Comment: I did not say it is the processor.  I said it is my setup.  That is why I asked.  I cannot have it, so can I have hyper-v without it.

Comment: You probably can, after you fix your BIOS settings.

Comment: I will look again.

Answer (score 1):

Second Level Address Translation has become a requirement for Server 2016.  It was not required for Server 2012 R2 or earlier, except when you wanted a GPU driver to be running in the system (as was the case for RemoteFX or any installation of Hyper-V on a client operating system like Windows 8 or Windows 10.)